# Como crear varios archivos CSV a partir de ejecucion de servicio web

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, archivo

En mi programa que llama a ciertos servicios web, me gustaria que en el resultado final se crearan differentes archivos CSV dependiendo si el `ProjectID` es diferente

En el codigo siguiente, en el filtro del array de `projectIDs` el llama a todos los numeros de proyecto, y lo manda a la llamada de servicio final.

En este momento el archivo final solo es uno solo contieniendo los 2 projectos diferentes.

Lo que busco hacer es que por cada projectID que exista, un archivo CSV se cree diferente y por ende se descargue.

Como puedo hacer esto?

Aqui esta el codigo:

Muchas gracias.

```
    string ExportTasksForAllProjects = "ExportTasksForAllProjects";
string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\ExportTasksForAllProjects\\{0}.csv", ExportTasksForAllProjects + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms")); //+ DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms") +  "_" + Guid.NewGuid() + );
String newLine = "";
var stream = File.CreateText(outCsvFile);

 WS.UserData[] userDataId = client.GetUserData(DataSourceId);

    List<string> multiUserIDs = new List<string>();

        foreach (var userdata in userDataId)
        {
            multiUserIDs.Add(userdata.List[0].ToString());
        }

        foreach (WS.ProjectMetaData proj in pr)
        {                                          
            string temp = "";   
            var AllProjectIds = proj.ProjectID;
            string[] projectIDs = new string[] { AllProjectIds }; // all projects       

            WS.TaskEntry[] resultGT3 = client.GetTasks3(projectIDs, multiUserIDs.ToArray());

            foreach (var item in resultGT3)
            {
                newLine = item.ProjectID + "," +
                    item.UserID + "," +
                    item.ProjectTitle + "," +
                    item.StartDate;

                stream.WriteLine(newLine);
            }
            stream.Close();  
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varias soluciones, una forma sería usando `File.CreateText()` para crear los diferentes archivos:

```
string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\ExportTasksForAllProjects\\{0}.csv", ExportTasksForAllProjects + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms"));
String newLine = "";
var stream = File.CreateText(outCsvFile);

   foreach (var item in resultGT3)
            {
               newLine  =      item.ProjectID + "," +
                                item.UserID + "," +
                                item.ProjectTitle + ","+
                                item.StartDate;

                      stream.WriteLine(newLine);

             }
     stream.Close();
```

Con esto puedes crear tus archivos `.csv` conteniendo los valores que se contienen dentro de `resultGT3`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Update:
Para crear diferentes archivos por proyecto:

```
foreach (WS.ProjectMetaData proj in pr)
       {     
        string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\ExportTasksForAllProjects\\{0}.csv", ExportTasksForAllProjects + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms")); //+ DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms") +  "_" + Guid.NewGuid() + );
        String newLine = "";
        var stream = File.CreateText(outCsvFile);
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Hice como me recomendaste pero solo crea un archivo y no contiene nada dentro de el (ningun record dentro del archivo csv)

Comment: @Aarancibia, tienes que revisar en la linea : foreach (var item in resultGT3) si en verdad resultGT3 tiene elementos!

Comment: Ya me funciono, pero solo crea un solo archivo que es el mismo que creaba antes con el contenido de los 2 projectsIDs

Comment: Te sugiero pongas tu código modificado para revisar cual es el problema, debería crear otro archivo ya que el valor de DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms") siempre esta variando.

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta con el codigo modificado. Gracias

Comment: actualicé la respuesta: si se desean crear archivos por cada proyecto, simplemente define dentro de foreach (WS.ProjectMetaData proj in pr)
       {

Comment: Si, al ponerlo adentro de (WS.ProjectMetaData proj in pr) me resulto y puedo crear archivos multiples dependiendo de cuantos proyectos tenga. Me funciono, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que recomendaria es que uses una libreria como ser [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) para generar la exportacion

Entonces tienes tu llamada al servicio que vuelcas en una clase que mapeas con CsvHelper

defines una clase

```
public class UserExport{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    //otras propiedades
}
```

y luego usarias

```
WS.UserData[] userData = client.GetUserData(DataSourceId);

List<UserExport> dataExport = new List<UserExport>();
foreach(var item in userData)
{
   dataExport.Add(new UserExport() { Id = item.NombreProp } );
}


using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(outCsvFile)                             
{ 
    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
    csv.WriteRecords(dataExport);
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. El problema que no logro cargar la libreria a partir de la console. me dice que la libreria Install-Package CsvHelper no funciona

Comment: que seria el "no funciona"? deberias explicarte un poco mejor. Si lo realizas de forma visual desde nuget tampoco te deja ? Sino podrias descargar la dll ubicarla en una carpeta y referenciarla

Comment: Si ya me funciono agregando las librerias directamente y las referencie. El problema era que el nuget no se logra conectar. Hice como me recomendaste pero me dice que NombreProp no existe extension cuando lo agredo. Hay algo mas que tengas que referenciar o agregar?

Comment: Se supone que no tienes que copiar y pegar, esa propiedad es la que devuelve la clase UserData del servicio web. Como no se como es la clase del web service puse "NombreProp"