# Problemas para separar archivo csv usando coma como separador

Tags: c#, visual-studio, archivo

Tengo una applicación que exporta el resultado en un archivo CSV. Estoy usando comas como separador de columnas, pero el problema que en unos de los parámetros de salida `item.SN` el contenido contiene también comas para separar el nombre; entonces el archivo crea columnas separando los datos en varias partes.

¿De que forma podría arreglar esto? He tratado varias formas pero no logro hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Aquí esta mi código:

```
foreach (WS.ProjectMetaData proj in pr)
{ 
    string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\ExportTasksForAllProjects\\{0}.csv", proj.ProjectTitle + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms"));
    String newLine = "";
    var stream = File.CreateText(outCsvFile);
    stream.WriteLine("ProjectName,Subject Name, UserID, Task StartDate");


     WS.UserData[] userDataId = client.GetUserData(DataSourceId);

        List<string> multiUserIDs = new List<string>();

            foreach (var userdata in userDataId)
            {
                multiUserIDs.Add(userdata.List[0].ToString());
            }
                                                     
                string temp = "";   
                var AllProjectIds = proj.ProjectID;
                string[] projectIDs = new string[] { AllProjectIds }; // all projects       

                WS.TaskEntry[] resultGT3 = client.GetTasks3(projectIDs, multiUserIDs.ToArray());

                foreach (var item in resultGT3)
                {                                        
                    newLine = item.ProjectTitle + "," +
                                item.SN + "," +         //Aqui el SN contiene commas entonces se separa en diferentes columnas              
                                item.UserID + "," +
                                item.StartDate;                                        

                    stream.WriteLine(newLine);
                }
                stream.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: no podrias reemplazar las comas del contenido del item.SN por algun otro valor, usarias el metodo Replace()

Comment: Hola, no puedo remplazarla por algun otro valor ya que es mandatorio que este separado el SN por comas, segun lo que piden.

Comment: Como te comente en una pregunta anterior http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5218/como-crear-varios-archivos-csv-a-partir-de-ejecucion-de-servicio-web/5219#5219 usa csvhelper para generar el archivo y valida asignando un valor con coma para ver como responde cuando el valor tiene un caracter igual al separado. Creo recordar que usa algo para encerrar el dato no se si era entre [] o si lo define entre comillas dobles

Comment: Si intente usar esa libreria pero no logre tener los resultados esperados, es por eso que busque otra forma

Comment: mm que raro, porque no lograste el resultado esperado ? que es lo que difiere. Sino podrias evaluar http://www.filehelpers.net/ es otra muy buena librerias

Comment: el resultado que buscaba era generar multiples archivo dependiendo de cuantas veces tenga un proyecto existente. Con esa libreria solo me generaba el mismo archivo conteniendo todos los proyectos sin dividirlos en multiples archivos

Comment: claro pero lo datos los fracionas generando instancias diferentes de la lista, o sea generas una lista de x items y envias a persistir con la librerias, luego creas otra lista con otro z items y envias a persistir asi generas cada archivo, es mas podrias ayudarte con linq para agrupar y en un foreach generar en un loop cada archivos, o sea programas orientado a objetos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tienes valores que contienen comas debes delimitarlo con comillas `"`

```
"Valor 1","Texto, que, contiene, comas","Valor 3"
```

(Importante, si estás abriendo el archivo en Excel, no debe haber ningún espacio entre los campos, es decir `"uno","dos"` **no** `"uno", "dos"`)

Entonces sería más sencillo si haces esto para todos tus valores

```
newLine = string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"", 
    item.ProjectTitle,
    item.SN,
    item.UserID,
    item.StartDate);
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Me funciono bien.

Answer (score 0):

Si no referimos a las especificaciones de un `csv`

[Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

en el titulo "**Basic rules**" describe

- Fields with embedded commas or double-quote characters must be quoted.

> 1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"

- Each of the embedded double-quote characters must be represented by a pair of double-quote characters.

> 1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck"

Deberias seguir las reglas del estandar para generar tu archivos.

Answer (score 0):

Como tienes tu código puedes agregar comillas, para mantener la [**especificación**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

```
foreach (var item in resultGT3)
        {                                        
          newLine = "\"" +item.ProjectTitle + "\",\"" +
          item.SN + "\",\"" +         //Aqui el SN contiene commas entonces se separa en diferentes columnas              
          item.UserID + "\",\"" +
          item.StartDate +"\"";                                          
          stream.WriteLine(newLine);
        }
```

ó

```
foreach (var item in resultGT3)
        {    
         newLine = string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"", 
         item.ProjectTitle,
         item.SN,
         item.UserID,
         item.StartDate);
         stream.WriteLine(newLine);
        }
```

Por ejemplo obtendrías:

```
"Valor 1","Otro, Valor, ok" , "valor 3" , Valor 4", "Valor 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

namespace WsConsultaExamen
{
public class ConsultaModel
{
public string C40FUM { get; set; }
public string C40NID { get; set; }
public string C40TID { get; set; }
public string C40DIG { get; set; }
public string C40NIP { get; set; }
public string C40FCC { get; set; }
public string C40NOM { get; set; }
public string C40TNO { get; set; }
public string C40GRF { get; set; }
public string C40FIN { get; set; }
public string C40LNE { get; set; }
public string C40FPI { get; set; }
public string C40TRF { get; set; }
public string C40GER { get; set; }
public string C40AUC { get; set; }
public string C40CLP { get; set; }
public string C40SUC { get; set; }

```
    public string C40EST { get; set; }

    public string C40IEB { get; set; }
    public string C40IEC { get; set; }
    public string C40IVC { get; set; }
    public string C40IVT { get; set; }
    public string C40IVA { get; set; }
    public string C40USR { get; set; }
    public string C40FUA { get; set; }

    public string C40HUA { get; set; }
    public string C40NO1 { get; set; }
    public string C40NO2 { get; set; }
    public string C40AP1 { get; set; }
    public string C40AP2 { get; set; }

}
public class ReponseConsultaModel
{
    public List<ConsultaModel> datosReponse { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código, además de corregir su formato y explicar _cómo responde esto a la pregunta_. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.